# Excel 2013 - Flowchart template - Click event

Tags: excel

If anyone has used the standard flowcharts template that comes with Excel 2013, can you help me with how the events are wired in the contents tab? When I click "project", it goes to project tab, for example. I checked the Right Click -> Format Shape, Assign Macro, Hyperlink, etc. None of them seem to explain the mechanism. I changed the name of a tab and i started getting "Reference is not valid" when I click on the shape (Project - for example).

Just to clarify the use case, Open Excel 2013, Select Flowchart Template and open a new worksheet, change any existing tab name - Say "Project" and when you click on the corresponding shape in "contents" tab, it will thrown an error.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the link object and click "edit hyperlink". Then in the right pane, highlight the tab that you want the link to go to, and click ok. This also works for the "back" and "next" buttons at the top of the template.